# NgbDatepicker return null when model is used any or object '{}'

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I found a problem when i used to NgbDatepicker

Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xnv11x

model is always return `null` when i set year = 0

Example: `0-10-25`. Could you please help me understand what has happened here?

Comment: where did you set the year

Comment: Why is that a problem? Its not a valid date, so its leaving it as null. Seems reasonable?

Comment: Have you seen what it does when you remove the day from the date? You get a third behaviour :)

Comment: As your opinion, why it does not return string as well as day or month is 0